# establish matrix and inversion of a uppertriangularized matrix

Tags: inverse

Trying to create an uppertriangularized matrix with Poisson Distribution, find its inverse and multiply the inverse by a vector, i.e.

```
mu=5; 
lambda=158;  
Daily = {a 158 element vector};
ME = UpperTriangularize[Table[(mu^(lambda + 1 - j) Exp[-mu])/(lambda + 1 - j)!, 
{i, lambda}, {j, lambda}]];
    Actual = Inverse[ME].Daily; 
    cumulative = FoldList[Plus, 0, Actual]
```

the notebook would not execute and displays a redline on the right edge of the screen and a statement below the code saying

```
ln(2) MatrixForm[ME[tt_, mm_] := UpperTriangularize[Table[(mm^(tt + 1 - j) Exp[-mm])/(tt + 1 - j)!, {i, lambda}, {j, lambda}]]]

Out(2) MatrixForm=
       Null
```

Comment: You're taking `MatrixForm` on a function definition...

Comment: [`LinearSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LinearSolve.html) will be more robust and faster than matrix inversion.